# From list of vector to list with R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list of vector : 
[[1]]

```
 [1] a  

 [2] f 

 [3] e       

 [4] a 

[[2]] 

 [1] f 

 [2] f

 [3] e
```

I would like to know if is there a way to transform it in a list (simple list of characters) like this :

```
 [1] a f e a  

 [2] f f e
```

Thank you

Comment: I could just guess, but you'd be likely to get better answers if you provided the output of `dput()` on your example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unlist`

```
l1 <- list(list("a", "f", "e", "a"),
           list("f", "f", "e"))

lapply(l1, unlist)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "f" "e" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "f" "f" "e"
```